# Has Morden issues?

Tags: synchronization, testnets, morden, ropsten

according to https://testnet.etherscan.io/, the last block has been mined more than 12 hours ago, whereas before more than one were mined per minute.
Has the difficulty changed so much ? Or has the testnet problems ?

Comment: Now https://testnet.etherscan.io/ is down…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The testnet was reset due to various complications, one being a consensus issue between Geth and Parity. You can read about it here:

https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/11/20/from-morden-to-ropsten/

See the bottom of the page for instructions on running on the new testnet, Ropsten.